# Interface USB and SPI flash (Boot PC from SPI)

Tags: usb, spi, flash, eeprom

Basically I am looking for a way to boot a PC from SPI flash. I'm talking about average AMD/Intel desktop mainboards. BIOS is already on SPI, but I need a way to also put the kernel and maybe initrd there.

It needs to be SPI flash and I probably can't use the one with the BIOS on it. 
You can boot from USB and I was wondering if there is some way to make the storage "backend" of an USB device SPI instead of NAND flash.

Comment: Yes, It's certainly possible to build a USB storage device which uses SPI flash as the storage medium.

Comment: You are mixing interface with NVM technology. SPI is just an interface. While NAND is non-volatile memory type. SPI interfaced memory could be NAND also. Whats the point in your idea instead of getting casual usb flash drive and boot from it instead?

Comment: @NStorm  The point is to create a bootable device which is read only. Chromebooks have a WP screw which protects at least the BIOS from being altered. I'd like to expand that to some other parts  of the system. Optical disks are not really used anymore and can't be updated readily. Write protection on USB drives works a bit different (less secure) than for say a SOIC8 eeprom where you just pull WP to ground. It is also easier to read all of the memory back. My hope was for some kind of USB to SPI adapter which acts as storage. I would not mind if it is slow, it's mostly for the kernel.

Comment: @brhans Any more info on that. I'm not an electronics guy so I can't really build a PCB from scratch. I'd need at least some kind of development board. I dunno if the average controller on a USB flash drive can handle an SPI eeprom.

Comment: btw. if there is another option instead of USB to boot from SPI eeproms let me know.

Comment: @spiusb - you would choose a microcontroller with both USB & SPI modules (from 1000's of options), choose one or more  SPI flash ICs and connect them to your micro, and write some firmware to make your micro appear as a mass-storage USB device...

Answer (score 1):

You can't boot from anything that BIOS doesn't supports. As basically your BIOS supports USB, HDD, ODD, Network boot - that's your only options.

As for the write protect - just get a USB flash drive with write protection switch. These are rare nowadays but still could be found. And finding one is much simplier than building your own "SPI USB". Especially for "not an electronics guy".

Actually that you are trying to do is to build your own "USB flash stick" with a slower serial interface between some sort of the USB controller and SPI memory. It would be pretty big project and I doubt the efforts are worth your goals since there are ready made products which just do their job already.

Comment: I have some of those sticks, but as said, they work differently.

Comment: It took me only a few minutes to find an example of USB Mass Storage backed by an SPI flash: https://infocenter.nordicsemi.com/topic/com.nordic.infocenter.sdk5.v13.0.0/usbd_msc_example.html  I'm sure there are many others...

Comment: @ChrisStratton if it took only a few minutes, care to spend one more to read last paragraph on my answer where I've already told that this is possible but pointless?